# python installation moved, pip stopped working

Tags: python, pip

I had Python 3.6 on my Windows machine under "C:\Program Files"
I wanted to upgrade it to 3.11.
Installer completed successfully, but new version was installed not in program files, but in "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311".

I moved Python311 directory to the "C:\Program Files" and python itself does work, but pip is not working anymore. when I am trying to do

pip --version

I am getting

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python311\Scripts\pip.exe" --version': The system cannot find the file specified.

Can someone please tell me what I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Try [changing your PYTHONPATH variable.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/17200348)

Comment: Try  python -m pip

Comment: @B Remmelzwaal I do not have PYTHONPATH environment variable. I can add it to my local environment, but what shall I put as its value?

@yfdgvf asdasdas  python -m pip does work properly, but how do I fix the pip itself?

Comment: @GaryGreenberg I'd recommend adding it and adapting the solution's PYTHONPATH to the directory you have moved Python to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't move installed programs around in windows. Your error is directly caused by this, the path of `python`(C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe) is hard coded into `pip` (and probably more places), so all you are doing is breaking stuff.

There is nothing wrong with python being installed in `AppData`. That is what that directory is for. At least for programs that are only installed for your user. If you really want to install to a different directory, then uninstall and reinstall. This time, choose `Customize installation` on the first screen of the installation. Also make sure to uninstall the 3.6 version and select `Add python.exe to PATH` in the new installation

Comment: Probably the best approach. Even if pip can be fixed, it's asking for trouble somewhere down the line.